# jQuery is messing with my PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, registration

I have a registration form that I'm working on and it's turning out to be a pain.

I'm very new to PHP, so please cut me some slack - haha.

I installed a jQuery plugin that allowed me to make inline labels for my textboxes. I also created an error box for any errors that occur during the registration process (invalid email, etc.). Here's some of my HTML/PHP code.

```
    <?php
    if($_POST['submit'])
    {
$signuperror = "Hello World";
     ?>

            <?php if($signuperror != "") { ?>
            <span id="signuperror"><?= $signuperror; ?></span>
            <?php } ?>
```

The problem was that the "error" of "Hello World" was not displaying when I clicked the submit button on my form. I copied and pasted this code onto a test.php document and it worked fine. So I knew that it had to be from my other html code. After troubleshooting almost every line of code, I found the culprit. It turns out that the jQuery plugin initialization for the inline labels was the problem.

```
    $(function(){
            $.fn.formLabels();
            $("form").submit(function(){
                var formVal = $("form").serialize();
                parent.$("#default div.results").html(formVal);
                return false
            })
        });
```

When I deleted this, it worked just fine (without my inline labels, of course).

What could I do to make BOTH the PHP and jQuery work.

Thanks.
- Ryan

Comment: `jQuery is messing with my PHP`. not possible

Comment: What's `parent` in `parent.$("#default div.results").html(formVal);`? have you assigned any value to `parent`? Also, what's the error you're getting?

Comment: @SamuelCook That's exactly what I thought. But now, can you explain why when I delete that plugin initialization that my PHP code works like it's supposed to?

Comment: @badZoke For this, I'm sorry, but I'm going to have to send you a link for the plugin. I didn't write this code - just simply downloaded it off the internet. Link: http://o2v.net/blog/jquery-formlabels-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of things here that are going on. Need to do this step by step.

1. Your PHP should either use `<?php` format or use `<?` short form but to be sure i would code all in `<?php` so its compatible everywhere
2. When you need to echo or output something use `<?php echo $variable; ?>` rather than `<?=`. Not that its no good or so but it will take out any php config issues with asp style output.
3. First test php output then check if statement.

Jquery is not messing with your PHP. That title is just as random as my answer.

Comment: `Jquery is not messing with your PHP. That title is just as random as my answer.` I understand this. I was just trying to put the focus on why when I took out that code, it worked fine. Hahaha. As for your answer, I changed it back to <?php ?> and it's still the same result.

Comment: Can you check what is being sent in post when you submit the form. Look into the page headers. The only case it will not hit hello world is when if statement on top is not satisfied. Try testing without IF first.

Comment: Okay. I changed the php code at the top of the html document to `<?php
$signuperror = "Hello World";
?>` and that worked. It displayed "Hello World" when the page loaded (along with the inline labels)... I'm assuming this is what you were saying for me to do.

Comment: After re-typing the IF it worked. Don't understand this at all. But hey, it works. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. The reason why it was not showing was that you might be sending data in get or you might not be sending it at all. Post your HTML first. Then post your jQuery and PHP is the last thing to check when your html is going to server in post or get. Then fix your php if needed. You can also do print_r($_POST) to print out post array for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the `return false` at the end of the `$("form").submit()` function. That means the jQuery function is taking the place of your form's POST action. You're not reloading the page synchronously, so you don't have any value for `$_POST["submit"]`. Get rid of the `return false` line, and see if the page reloads as you're expecting.

Comment: After looking back over everything, the plugin initialization was incorrect. I was supposed to use.
`$(function(){
         $.fn.formLabels();
   });` After changing this, I still got the same result.